# Do we need "duplicate of this [link]" type of comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags, deleted-comments

Today I dupe-hammered this question: [Android 9 (Pie) retrofit API security error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55135532/7666442), so it was closed immediately.

After that a user wrote a comment on the question, something like:

> duplicate of [link to another question]

I flagged that comment as a no longer needed, because I had already added that question as a duplicate after closing it.

The comment is deleted now but my flag was declined.

[image: flag history]

- Why was my NLN flag declined?
- Do we need "duplicate of this [link]" type of comments? Especially after added the linked post already is in the duplicate target list?

Comment: I know this is getting downvotes, but I agree with you. This is just spammy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It may very well have been me who declined this flag. I vaguely remember declining a flag on a comment like this one earlier today. Then, I noticed that the question had, in fact, been closed as a duplicate of the very same question that the comment proposed, so I went ahead and deleted the comment.

A couple of things to note:

1. There's no way for a moderator to "reverse" or "change" the dispensation of a comment flag, so even if I had considered it to be a worthwhile investment of time to go back and change the flag's status to "helpful", I couldn't.
2. When processing comment flags, moderators don't necessarily see the full context of the question on which the comment is posted unless we go through extra steps to open the question in a new tab. That's not always worth it for comment flags.
3. We get a rather unfortunate number of people flagging "possible duplicate of" comments because they *disagree* with them. That's not a valid reason to flag a comment, and I'm not going to delete a comment because some flagger disagrees that a question is a duplicate. As such, I decline *most* of these. Occasionally, that means a false negative. On balance, for these types of comments, I'd rather have a false negative than a false positive.

To answer your real question, no, we don't need "possible duplicate of" comments when the question has already been closed as a duplicate of the exact question suggested in the comment. That's a perfect reason to flag as "no longer needed".

Please don't flag "possible duplicate of" comments when:

1. The question is not marked as a duplicate,
2. The comment suggests a *different* duplicate than the question is actually marked as (unless you use your gold tag badge powers to *add* that dupe-target),
3. You disagree that the question is a duplicate and are hoping that a moderator will delete the comment as a way of sweeping that possibility under the rug.

Comment: Can we get some sort of warning and/or ban for users who fall into (3)?

Comment: Do you make any concession for the age of the 'possible dupe' comment? I agree with the fact you shouldn't attempt to sweep a suggestion under the rug while the question is still active, but sometimes I will see such a comment that I both disagree with, and that's on an open question that hasn't been active for months or years. I would usually flag that as NLN. All comments should be treated as ephemeral; we can't keep every such comment around forever just because one person once speculated it *might* be related.

Comment: @IanKemp There are automated flag bans in place, but those only kick in if that constitutes 25% or more of their flagging activity.

Comment: @Ian Nothing automated, except what Haem pointed out. It could be solved with a moderator message, but most of the time, it's not worth the hassle. Simply clicking "dismiss" is enough to solve the problem, and involves far less time investment. The real head-scratcher is when these "possible duplicate of" comments get flagged as "harrassment, bigotry, or abuse". Oh well, that's why we have actual human moderators process flags, rather than robots.

Comment: @Michael No, not really. Not given that close votes age away, and the close-vote queue currently has (and has had for a long time) ~10k questions in it. Good chance that lots of *actual* duplicates get missed being marked as such because there are simply too many of them and not enough reviewers.  Either way, the comments are still *useful*, both directly and because they put the question in the "Linked" questions sidebar. When you're researching an issue, the extra information can be useful. There's no real noise consideration here, so no reason to delete these comments.